# Como podria luego de declarar un loop con while,sacar elementos del mismo?

Tags: python, if, while

Como podria en este caso sacar las edades que son menores a 18, las que son mayores a 18 y luego imprimirlas..?Yo lo hice asi pero me funciona el loop pero no el print.

```
Edad_persona=int(input("Ingrese su edad:"))
while Edad_persona!=999:
    print("Ingrese otra edad")
    Edad_persona=int(input("Ingrese su edad:"))
if Edad_persona<18:
    print("La cantidad de personas menores a 18 años son" ,Edad_persona)
if Edad_persona>=18:
    print("La cantidad de personas mayores a 18 años son" ,Edad_persona)
print("Programa terminado")
```

**Edición** (Movido aquí desde un comentario)

En ese caso,si yo quiero ahora sumar las edades menores y mayores para luego sacar un promedio, yo lo intente de esta manera pero no me da...

```
Edad_persona=int(input("Ingrese su edad:"))
menores=1
mayores=0
Menores_promedio=0
Mayores_promedio=0
while Edad_persona!=999: 
    Edad_persona=int(input("Ingrese su edad:"))
if Edad_persona<18: 
    menores=menores+1 
if Edad_persona>18: 
    mayores=mayores+1 
Menores_promedio=(Menores_promedio+(Edad_persona<18))
Mayores_promedio=(Mayores_promedio+(Edad_persona>18))
print("Los menores a 18 son:" ,menores) 
print("Los mayores a 18 son:" ,mayores) 
print("El promedio de los menores es de:" ,((Menores_promedio)/menores))
```

Comment: el if debe ejecutarse dentro del while?

Comment: Creo que si lo que a mi me interesaria saber es como hago para poner los valores que son menores a 18 y ponerles un print y lo mismo con los mayores de 18..

Comment: Ivan si solo quieres contar el numero de menores y mayores de 18 años usa dos variables declaradas antes del `while` inicializadas a 0 (`menores = 0`, `mayores = 0`), mete los condicionales en el `while` y ve sumando 1 a la variable que corresponda. Terminado el `while` imprimes las variables.  Si necesitas almacenar las edades usa una lista para usarlas fuera del ciclo. Y cambia `if Edad_persona>=18:` por `else:`, es más eficiente.  Te recomiendo pensar detenidamente en lo que hace tu código y en que almacena `Edad_persona`, que valor tiene cuando se sale del `while`, etc,

Comment: Cuando realices preguntas te sugiero tomarte un tiempo en redactar adecuadamente la misma, explicando detalladamente a que problema te enfrentas, cual es la entrada esperada, cual la salida, que es lo que falla en lo que has intentado, etc.  Te aseguro que el tiempo que inviertas lo recuperarás ya que recibirás mejores respuestas y más rápido si no obligas a otros usuarios a deducir que quieres, lo que generalmente desemboca en respuestas erradas (y a la perdida de esfuerzo y tiempo de quién responde) o que los usuarios simplemente pasen de la pregunta o voten para su cierre.  Un saludo

Comment: Gracias por el comentario!En ese caso,si yo quiero ahora sumar las edades menores y mayores para luego sacar un promedio, yo lo intente de esta manera pero no me da...en el prox comentario lo pongo porque es muy largo

Comment: Edad_persona=int(input("Ingrese su edad:"))
menores=1
mayores=0
Menores_promedio=0
Mayores_promedio=0
while Edad_persona!=999:
                Edad_persona=int(input("Ingrese su edad:"))
  if Edad_persona<18:
   menores=menores+1 
  if Edad_persona>18:
   mayores=mayores+1
  Menores_promedio=(Menores_promedio+(Edad_persona<18))
  Mayores_promedio=(Mayores_promedio+(Edad_persona>18))

print("Los menores a 18 son:" ,menores)
print("Los mayores a 18 son:" ,mayores)
print("El promedio de los menores es de:" ,((Menores_promedio)/menores))

Comment: @Ivan. Puedes siempre editar tu pregunta para añadir información relevante, en lugar de hacerlo en los comentarios donde no puedes formatear el código. He convertido tus dos últimos comentarios en una edición de la pregunta (puedes eliminarlos de la zona de comentarios)

Answer (score 0):

El código que suminstras con tu intento de calcular el número de mayores y menores, tiene problemas importantes que denotan quizás un intento demasiado apresurado de lanzarse a programar sin haber comprendido las bases.

Intentaré ayudarte con esta cuestión, pero debes plantearte seriamente seguir un buen cursillo o libro introductorio para comprender los conceptos básicos sobre bucles y condicionales.

Esto son los problemas que presenta tu código:

- El bucle `while` en tu código se repetirá mientras el usuario introduzca edades distintas de 999, pero cada nueva edad introducida se vuelve a guardar siempre en la misma variable, con lo que se pierden las entradas anteriores. Una vez sales de ese bucle, la variable `Edad_persona` tendrá sólo la última edad introducida.
- Para arreglar en parte ese problema, el código que mira si la edad es mayor o menor de 18 debería formar parte también del bucle.
- La línea `Menores_promedio=(Menores_promedio+(Edad_persona<18))` no funciona como crees. `Edad_persona<18` es un "booleano", es decir, un valor que sólo puede ser `True` o `False`. Por tanto estás sumando a `Menores_promedio` un booleano, en lugar de sumar la edad. Entiendo que tal vez querías hacer "sumar la edad si es menor de 18", pero precisamente para estas cosas están los `if`.
- El problema anterior se resuelve metiendo la línea que actualiza `Menores_promedio` en el `if` que comprobaba si la edad era menor de 18.
- ¿Y si la edad es 18? Ese caso no lo estás contando. Ya que con 18 años se es mayor de edad, entiendo que debería contarse en el caso `>=18`.
- Los nombres de las variables no son apropiadas, ya que `Menores_promedio` no es el promedio (de momento) sino sólo la suma, por tanto mejor se llamaría `suma_menores`. Además, siguiendo las recomendaciones típicas, los nombres de variables no deberían comenzar por mayúscula.
- Conviene comentar lo que hace el programa. Te ayudará a entenderlo.

Poniendo en práctica todas estas ideas, el código quedará así:

```
# Inicializamos con cero contadores y sumas
n_menores=0
n_mayores=0
suma_menores=0
suma_mayores=0

# Leemos la primera edad
edad_persona=int(input("Ingrese su edad:"))
while edad_persona != 999:
    # Si la edad es != 999 la procesamos
    if edad_persona < 18:
        n_menores = n_menores+1 
        suma_menores = suma_menores + edad_persona
    if edad_persona >= 18: 
        n_mayores = n_mayores+1 
        suma_mayores = suma_mayores + edad_persona
    # Leemos la edad de la siguiente (y con este nuevo valor
    # se repetirá todo el while)
    edad_persona=int(input("Ingrese su edad:"))

# Hemos salido del while, tenemos los resultados
print("Los menores a 18 son:", n_menores) 
print("Los mayores a 18 son:", n_mayores) 
print("El promedio de los menores es de:" ,((suma_menores)/n_menores))
```